# creating an large array of objects c++

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I need to create a large array(1000) of histograms where each histogram is slightly different. I am new to C++ and my first thought on how to do this was using a for loop which will create the histogram and add it to the array in the loop, but ive run into the issue of variable names (which i expected). How can i make the variable name of each histogram different while adding them in the loop?

sorry if that was poorly worded.

Comment: C++ has built-in arrays; only one name needed. Better yet, use `std::vector`.

Comment: We can help you better if you show us the relevant parts of your code ;)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to [include](http://whathaveyoutried.com) [code](http://sscce.org), even if it's clunky or not working, otherwise it's hard to understand your point of view. Also, you can use `Histogram myHistograms[1000]` or `std::vector<Histrogram> myHistograms`. But the actual implementation depends on your `Histogram`, especially its constructor and assignment methods.

Comment: You may have to use dynamic memory as most compilers have smaller limit for static memory allocations.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like what you want is a histogram class where each instance is a little different.

```
class Histogram {
    unsigned m_count;
    std::string m_label;
public:
    Histogram(std::string label) : m_count(0), m_label(label) {}
    std::string & label () { return m_label; }
    std::string label () const { return m_label; }
    unsigned & count () { return m_count; }
    unsigned count () const { return m_count; }
};
```

It might be easier to manage these within a `map` rather than a `vector` (unless you can actually classify the input into a number), but each histogram will need a unique label.

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Histogram> > histograms;

while (more_input()) {
    input = get_input();
    std::string classification = classify_input(input);
    if (histograms[classification] == 0)
        histograms[classification]
            = std::unique_ptr<Histogram>(new Histogram(classification));
    histograms[classification]->count() += 1;
}
```

Comment: as it turns out i am an idiot and i was doing the wrong thing all along. Thank you all so much for your help though.